# Vim ignores color 255, as if it doesn't support the 256 ones

Tags: syntax-highlighting, terminal, colorscheme, color

**Update:** it works, if I set the main bg color (white) as `ctermbg=231` (it was `015`). So it seems that color values in Vim syntax highlight settings shouldn't be mixed: *if one uses color codes from the 16 color palette, he should use it consistently*.

[image: cursor line color is correct]

The question then boils down to:

**why it used to work with mixed values just a couple of weeks ago?**

---

**Original post:**

I have a problem: Vim doesn't display some highlight colors, at least the `255` one (slightly grey). Color 022 (greenish) is displayed, which I assume means that the 256 colors are supported, since `022` doesn't belong to the system colors according to the xterm colors chart. Could someone please advise something about this. Either how this can be fixed, or where should I look to fix it?

Some details: I seem to have all necessary settings in both the terminal (Gnome terminal 3.36.2, as well as Terminator) and Vim.

In the `bashrc`:

```
export TERM='xterm-256color'
```

In the `vimrc` (this is the complete file, for purposes of reproducing the issue):

```
set nocompatible
set t_Co=256
set t_ut=
set cursorline
colorscheme default
set syntax=vim

hi Normal ctermbg=015 ctermfg=000
hi CursorLine cterm=none ctermbg=255 ctermfg=000

"set notermguicolors
"set termencoding=utf-8
"set term=xterm-256color
"set background=light
```

The commented options have been tried with various values in various combinations, which didn't affect the issue in any way.

1. **The terminals I tried show colors correctly** (I in purpose added the white color to the grayscale ramp line to see that color 255 and color 231 are displayed distinctly):

[image: perl script output to show 256 colors]

As one can see, the terminal displays all the colors, including the white (231) and slightly grey (255).

2. **When I start vim** `vim -u ~/Documents/vimrc --noplugin ~/Documents/vimrc` to edit the vimrc file shown above, **I see no cursor line**, though it's set:

[image: vim no cursor line color]

3. But **if I change `ctermbg` to `022`, it works**:

[image: vim cursor line color is correct]

I also have tried other colors: 225, 051 — it worked. But color 255 doesn't.

4. **The issue seems to have no relation to the CursorColumn syntax group**, since other groups don't display color 255 too.
5. **It all used to work** a couple of weeks ago on the same system, with probably the same vim binary and the same vimrc file. But since I had a data loss I freshly installed Fedora 32 and now am trying to restore my vim config:

   - the bashrc file is lost, so I might have some setting there, which affected the issue;
   - the vim directory with after/* scripts is lost (though it must have been empty);

I've searched in all set options for '256', '16' and 'color' and found nothing. So I virtually have no idea what the cause of this might be. Could someone give an advice? Thank you in advance.

Comment: color 255 is `Grey93` which is `#eeeeee` https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/